# What are the security implications of Chrome Custom Tabs vs. WebView?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I know that there are a lot of things to consider when using a WebView to load 3rd party content in terms of security as the WebView runs within your process. Which process does Chrome Custom Tabs work in? Are there similar security concerns for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Custom Tabs runs with [Chrome multi-process architecture](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture). Chrome processes are separate from the app processes. Hence, there is much stronger protection from 3rd party content with Chrome Custom Tabs than with WebView, app security is improved.